# FBRequestConnection Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-events

I am trying to get all the events from a Facebook page and store them in variables
eventDate
coverPhoto
eventName
eventInfo etc etc...

I have the Facebook SDK all set up and now am trying to get this info using the FBRequest.startWithGraphPath.

Need some pointers on where to go with this.. all the Facebook docs are in objective C. I have seen on the Facebook docs it has all the relevant fields like
is_date_only,name,cover I need just not sure how to declare this in code to get them out.

heres my code;

```
var completionHandler = {
            connection, result, error in
            } as FBRequestHandler;


    func fetchFacebookEventInfo() {

        FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/eventtest/events", completionHandler: completionHandler)





    }
```

Thanks in advance!!